# Empty regex returns and repetitions

Tags: regex, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to retrieve some content from a csv, am converting the list objects to strings, and then am attempting to use regex to reduce a bunch of strings to repetitive parts (eventually to count them. Specifically, I am trying to gather call_number data in a library and look at shelving statistics.

Everything before and after what will be a larger process is working. What you see here is the section in which I keep running into a roadblock.

But all I keep getting is the same content from the original csv back into the new one.
You can see I use print statements throughout to see what is working and what is not.

But when I try to print what should be content as produced by the regex, I get 'None."

What am I failing to understand about this?
Is there an order of operations issue, how do I specifically get the regex results as the content of the new csv? 'call_interim2.csv'

thank you in advance.

'''

```
with open('call_interim.csv', 'r', newline='') as call_intrm:

        print('step 2')

        with open('call_interim2.csv', 'w') as call_intrm2:
            cano_reader = csv.reader(call_intrm)
            for line in cano_reader:
                line = (str(line))#.strip(',')
                row = re.search('^.+\.', line)

                print(row)
                cano_writer2 = csv.writer(call_intrm2)

                for row in call_intrm:
                    cano_writer2.writerow([row])
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the `\` is not properly being escaped. Look into using the python [raw string notation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). For example:

```
row = re.search(r'^.+\.', line)
```

From the `regex` docs:

> ...The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in a string literal prefixed with 'r'. So r"\n" is a two-character string containing '\' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python code using this raw string notation.

Beyond that, I'd supply some examples in your question to show what your input string looks like so it can be tested.

Comment: Let me look at the 'r' option today and see how this goes. thanks.

Comment: Conclusion: I am going to use a different approach for this than regex - but in the future, another opportunity may arise soon enough. Thank you